# Keep the user logged in with phone auth

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't figure out how to see phone number in firebase and I don't know how to make the user stay logged in.

I have tried a lot of code didn't work out for me:

```
class VerifyCodeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Code: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func Verify(_ sender: Any) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: defaults.string(forKey: "authVID")!, verificationCode: Code.text!)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error:\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else {
                print("Phone Number:\(String(describing: user?.phoneNumber))")
                let userInfo = user?.providerData[0]
                print("provider ID: \(String(describing: userInfo?.providerID))")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "maininf", sender: Any?.self)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase iOS SDK keeps the user logged in for you once they actually log in. Does the code you provided print any error stack? Have you followed the instructions in the firebase tutorial for this carefully? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start

Comment: handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...    <- i don't now what to write if i did know i wold not asked man thank you 
}

Comment: I need you to give me an output of your code. The **console log**. The text that gets printed in Xcode when something happens in your app - when you actually turn it on. I'd love to help you, but I need more information.

Comment: see the answer below if that's helps

Comment: That's a source code, that's **not** an output. Output is when text starts moving and being printed in the lower section **below** your source code. See the picture in the link: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/images/download/attachments/29004939/ti_log_in_xcode.png

Comment: That's your phone number. That means user is logged in. If you want to keep your user object and pass it, implement method `prepareForSegue` and instead of `Any?.self` send the `user` object. In the `prepareForSegue` you would obtain your `user` object in `sender` parameter and you can do with it whatever you desire.

Comment: Also, for safety, don't post here (on Stack Overflow) that private information - maybe edit out significant amount of digits e.g.: "Optional("+******669515")" - it's understandable from that.

Comment: every thing works good but i want to save this info to firebase and let the user to add photo and a name and keep sign in

Comment: look brother thanks for all of what you did but look how can i define user

Comment: Well you already have it `Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in` - just use it. The object called `user`. You can fully modify it as you wish. For any other information, use the Firebase Database.

Comment: hahaha bro you just helps me with 1 word is that fix keep the user logged in